# How I change the weight from a text button?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to change the font weight of text in the button, but only bold works, i.e. if I would change to medium or regular, it won't work. I use xcode 13.

There is the code:

```
            Button("Login") {}.font(.title.bold())
            .font (.title3)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .padding(20)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .background(Color("ButtonColor"))
            .cornerRadius(4.0)
```

Comment: have you tried `.fontWeight(.medium)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use it like

```
    Button("Login") {
    }
    .font(.title.weight(.heavy))   // << here !!
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Works, thank you so munch friend